# Was Te Fiti inspired by the Firebird Suite?

Tags: moana

I recognize that there's an actual myth behind the creation of Te Fiti in *Moana*.   But was her animated design:

[image: tefiti]

inspired by the character from Fantasia 2000's Firebird Suite?

[image: firebird]

The similarities in design are too close to be coincidental, I believe.

Is there evidence of this influence?

Answer (score 6):

Te Fiti and the character you picture are typical examples of the Mother Earth archetype. Their designs are fairly primeval depictions of Gaia anthropomorphized. Slightly sexualized women, long flowing hair, sometimes made of moss and grass. A Google image search for Gaia or mother earth personified shows many similar examples. These are generic depictions of a theme common to many religions and cultures.